# How to know if the stack is completely created using AWS SDK for Cloud Formation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sdk-js

I am using AWS SDK and creating stacks using CloudFormation templates. When I call the create Stack method, it gets executed perfectly and the call back returns a StackID. The problem here is stack is created but the resources inside the stack are still getting created and the whole create process is not completed. How will I know in my javascript that the whole creation process is completed?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a waiter for [`stackCreateComplete`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CloudFormation.html#stackCreateComplete-waiter):

```
var params = {
  StackName: 'name or the unique stack ID'
};
cloudformation.waitFor('stackCreateComplete', params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```